# Spring WebFlux - How to print response as String instead of object using WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, alfresco, project-reactor

I have a Mono like below:

```
    private void getNodeDetail() {
        Mono<String> mono = webClient.get()
                .uri("/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/f37b52a8-de40-414b-b64d-a958137e89e2")
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);

        System.out.println(mono.subscribe());
        System.out.println(mono.block());
    }
```

**Questions**: The first sysout shows me `reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber@77114efe` while using block() it shows me what I need (json String). But I want to use Aysnc approach. So, given above, does it mean my target system (Alfresco in this case) DO NOT support async calls? If that is not the case, how can I print the response on the console in String format using `subscribe()`, just like `block()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [subscribe()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe--) method returns a `Disposable` object:

```
 public final Disposable subscribe()
```

The expected way to print the response on the console is to actually use the `doOnNext` operator, like this:

```
private void getNodeDetail() {
    webClient.get()
            .uri("/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/f37b52a8-de40-414b-b64d-a958137e89e2")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .doOnNext(response -> System.out.println(response))
            .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot. Saved my day.

Comment: Then please consider upvoting the answer and accept it as correct so that others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!